# How to burn files, or move

Tags: files, iso

So, I have CHROMEBOOK, and I want install Ubuntu. I download ubuntu files (~1GB), ISO format, but, I dont know, how to put there files to my USB?
Just help me please :)

Comment: Installing Ubuntu on Chromebooks is [not officially supported](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8025/how-to-resolve-conflicting-information-about-chrubuntu-policy-status) and is off-topic here. Feel free to ask at our sister site [Unix.SE] though!

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can use rufus. Download it here https://rufus.akeo.ie/.

WARNING: Make sure the USB is for this purpose otherwise back it up. You don't want to loose your files :).

1. At the very top you select the device (USB) you would like the ISO to be put on.
2. Click on the disk icon to browse to your ISO.
3. Hit the start button.

If all went well you should have a bootable USB drive with ubuntu on it.

Comment: If you don't own a windows machine you can have a look at unetbootin it should probably work on chromebook.

Comment: Sorry If I didn't answer your question properly. This link explains how it can be done, https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/795730-how-to-easily-install-ubuntu-on-chromebook-with-crouton.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of extra steps such as enabling developer mode.

[Here is a guide](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/795730-how-to-easily-install-ubuntu-on-chromebook-with-crouton)